# WPF design-time context menu

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, contextmenu

I am trying to create a custom wpf control, I'm wondering how I can add some design-time features. I've googled and can't seem to get to my goal.

So here's my simple question, how can I add an entry to the design-time context menu for my WPF usercontrol? The context menu by default has entries View Code,View XAML, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to check out [the WPF Designer Extensibility documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546938.aspx). Specifically it sounds like you want to [create a custom MenuAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907308.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This will help you get the context menu you require, although this applies to datagrid's still applicable;
[WPF DataGrid Design-time Walkthrough](https://web.archive.org/web/20150628193953/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/11/07/wpf-datagrid-design-time-walkthrough.aspx)

Comment: It seems the link to 'WPF DataGrid Design-time Walkthrough' is out of date and no longer valid.
Do you happen to have a local version of this article or Demo projects left?